# Exact match in regex character classes

Tags: regex

Consider the following string

```
'35=_-235-b-35=35-35=2-135=a-35=123-235=2-35=a-53=1-53=a-553=b'
```

I'd like to extract everything that matches `35=` followed by 1 or 2 characters.
What I came up with is the following regex

```
\d[35]=[A-Za-z0-9]{1,2}
```

The problem is the character class `[35]` matches both `35=` and `53=`.
How can I achieve an exact match for a character class?

Any suggestions, or different approaches are very much appreciated!

Comment: `[35]` is a **character class**.  A *character set* or *charset* is something else entirely, not related to regexes. (fixed)

Comment: Thanks for pointing this out, Alan!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why not just `35` instead of `\d[35]` ?

Answer (score 1):

to match 35= followed by one or two alphanumeric char you can use

35=\w{1,2}

Felix